# How can I make the filter on a URL query string persistent using node and sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am working on a browser app using node.js and sequelize. It is a classroom exercise simulating a Library Management System. One of the functions of the app is to produce a paginated listing of rows in a SQLite3 table. I have a URL query string that has a filter, based on a nav selection in my browser. The initial value of the query string is as follows:

`http://localhost:3000/book?page=1&filter=checked_out`

(it comes from a nav selection for listing checked_out books)

The results of the query return a collection of rows that has more than a page worth of items, which initiates a pagination function that displays a button for each of the two pages <1><2>. The first page displays as it should, presenting 10 rows. However, if I click on button <2>, I go to the second page OK, but the list is no longer filtered because the query string looks like this:

`http://localhost:3000/book?page=2`

(no more filter)

The router file knows to apply the filter when req.query.filter === 'checked_out'. My problem is I cannot figure out how to make the filter persist after the initial query.

The program knows it needs page 2, but it doesn't know about the filter.

How do I fix this? I have searched the sequelize docs to no avail.

Comment: you just need add filter to your second url when you generating it.
add code of generating pagination url.

Comment: I am embarrassed to say that I discovered my problem and it was pretty simple. I had a filter variable initialized. However I never set it to a value. Therefore, when the ternary command in the href for the pagination button tested the value, it always came back undefined and therefore was not included in the URI. How do I flag this as answered?